# SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I am invoking the function `SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath("LOGS", 16)` in a custom SharePoint 2016 feature. However, I get the following error:

```
The value of the argument '16' is an unsupported enum type. 
Parameter name: verCompatLevel
```

I have some questions:

1. Why are there still references to SharePoint 2013 (v15) even if we are writing and executing code for SharePoint 2016?

   2. Is there some enum that can provide the value using the version of SharePoint as a reference? E.g.
   3. I see references to 15 even if the browser's address window. Why is that? Should it not be 16?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First I though it have something to do with `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration.dll` reference.

Error occured by this call:

`var layoutsPath = SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS", 16);`

Comment: Are you having the problem too, or are you suggesting a resolution? I am sorry, I do not quite see the answer in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even for SharePoint 2016, you still need to give 15 as the hive path. But you will get the 16-hive path as result.
So the code should look like below
 SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath("LOGS", 15)
Which give you the path as "16\LOGS"

Hope this helps!!!